# PHP get min and max values from 50 random numbers?

Tags: php, for-loop, random, max, min

```
<?php
 echo "<table border='1'><br />";
  for ($row = 0; $row < 10; $row ++) {
   echo "<tr>";
   for ($col = 0; $col < 5; $col ++) {
   $rand = rand (1, 200);
     echo "<td>", $rand, "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here is code but my question is how can I find max and min from values of the table? Do I have to make random numbers somehow into array?

Comment: why don't use `max`, `min` function of array in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following without changing much of your code

```
<?php
   $array = array();  // <-- added code

   echo "<table border='1'><br />";
   for ($row = 0; $row < 10; $row ++) {
       echo "<tr>";
       for ($col = 0; $col < 5; $col ++) {
           $rand = rand(1, 200);
           $array[] = $rand;   // <-- added code
           echo "<td>", $rand, "</td>";
       }
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";

   $min = min($array);  // <--- added code
   $max = max($array);  // <--- added code
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it out the max and min value of an aray in PHP using library function.

```
for($col = 0; $col < 5; $col ++) {
    $rand[] = rand (1, 200);
}

echo $max = max($rand)."<br/>";
echo $min = min($rand)."<br/>";

print_r($rand);
```